# spring boot multi-profile configuration reads property from different profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am adding the multi-profile external configuration as specified in the 
my `application.yml` is as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml)

```
   spring:
      profiles:
        active: prod
    server:
      context-path: '/webAppName'
      port: 8989

    ---
    spring:
      profiles: prod

    executor-names:
      - wasTaskExecutor=wm/default
      - taskExecutorUWS=wm/default_uws

    ---
    spring:
      profiles: qa

    datacollector:
        jndi-name: jdbc/qaCipDs

    ---
    spring:
      profiles: dev

    ruleapp-dir: res_data

    executor-names:
```

In my code I am checking, if `ruleapp-dir` is not null, execute `dev` specific code block.

When I run, I notice that the `executor-names` populate correctly but `ruleapp-dir` also getting mapped to `res-data` as in `dev` profile.
Note: I got this working by accessing the environment.getactiveprofiles but would like to know why the `ruleapp-dir` gets a value when it is existing only in `dev` profile.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it might be worth removing the extra line between `profiles: dev` and `ruleapp-dir: res_data`